# Intentservice issues in upgrading to Android Oreo

Tags: android

I am using IntentService class to fetch data from the server and will load it to the UI thread using event bus library. But I found that in SDK 26, they have implemented some background limitations. Should I implement JobScheduler API by replacing the IntentService? or what will happen if I continue to use IntentService class even in SDK 26? Couldn't get any traces of information about using IntentServices in oreo from the official docs.

Comment: JobScheduler won't work correctly in Oreo device